# what is MD5CryptoServiceProvider and what it can do?

Tags: asp.net

what is the meaning of MD5CryptoServiceProvider and what it can do can any body tell me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a [.NET Hash class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5cryptoserviceprovider.aspx). It allows you create non-reversible signatures of data, that are used mainly for matching passwords.

Rather use [SHA256](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256cryptoserviceprovider.aspx) and above nowadays though, as MD5 is not of much use anymore cryptographically, other than doing Hash checks on downloaded files.

EDIT for Example on SHA256:

```
byte[] data = new byte[DATA_SIZE];
byte[] result;

SHA256 shaM = new SHA256Managed();
result = shaM.ComputeHash(data);
```

This is a code example straight from MSDN (normal hashing). As you see, it is also quite simple.

Now using the CryptoProvider, check this link [here](http://www.developersdex.com/csharp/message.asp?p=1111&r=6747388), which is a forum post, but shows usage quite nicely.

Comment: how can i use SHA256 explain pro grammatically

Answer (score 1):

It helps you take the [MD5 hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) of a stream. It's not ASP.NET specific, by the way - any .NET code can use it.

You generally use a hash function when you want to be able to verify that a piece of data presented at two different times is the same (e.g. for passwords or file consistency). MD5 isn't considered very secure these days - there are other hashes (e.g. SHA-256) which are harder to attack. (An attack generally consists of an attacker knowing the hash, and then finding some piece of data which hashes to the same value, but without knowing the original data.)

Comment: can we use SHA-256 in asp.net? if yes how can explain programmatically

Comment: Yes, and you'd use it exactly the same way as for MD5, but with the SHA256* classes.